# List with various \item styles

Tags: lists

I'm trying to design a basic "interview format" consisting on a series of questions and answers, which I want to typeset in different styles like, for instance, boldface for questions with a leading "Q:" and normal text for answers with a leading "A:"

so far I've the following code that produces what I want, but is a bit cumbersome:

```
\begin{list}{}{}
   \item[\textbf{Q:}] \textbf{This is the first question}
   \item[A:] And this is the answer
   \item[\textbf{Q:}] \textbf{This is the second question}
   \item[A:] Another answer
\end{list}
```

The result is:

[image]

I even managed to define a new environment and a couple of commands to save typing:

```
\newenvironment{interview}
  {\begin{list}{}{}}
  {\end{list}}

\newcommand{\question}[1]{\item[\textbf{Q:}] \textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\item[A:] #1}

\begin{interview}
   \question {This is the first question}
   \answer {And this is the answer}
   \question {This is the second question}
   \answer {Another answer}
\end{interview}
```

This satisfies me enough, but I wonder if that could have been defined in any other way to avoid enclosing the argument of each "item" between curly braces, like we do in normal "itemize" lists. **Put otherwise: Is it possible to define things in a way that one can write something like this??:**

```
\begin{interview}
   \question This is the first question
   \answer And this is the answer
   \question This is the second question
   \answer Another answer
\end{interview}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start `\bfseries` for questions and restore `\normalfont` for answers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{interview}
  {\begin{list}{}{}}
  {\end{list}}

\newcommand{\question}{\bfseries\item[Q:]}
\newcommand{\answer}{\normalfont\item[A:]}

\begin{document}

\begin{interview}
\question This is the first question

\answer And this is the answer

\question This is the second question

\answer Another answer
\end{interview}

\end{document}
```

The blank lines between the items are a personal preference; I believe they're better than indenting the code.

[image]

Comment: Ah! simple but elegant solution. Does what I wanted. I should have realized myself...

Comment: @OrestesMas After all, each question is followed by an answer… `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to define a new list style, so that you could type

```
  \begin{interview}
    \item This is the first question
    \item And this is the answer
    \item This is the second question
    \item Another answer
  \end{interview}
```

to produce

[image]

The main thing you need to do is to change the default behaviour of the `\item` command so that it puts in your **Q:** and **A:** markers. Here's the code that does this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\realitem\item% save the "real" \item command
\newcommand\questionansweritem{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}
  \realitem[\ifodd\theenumi\textbf{Q:}\else\textbf{A:}\fi]
}
\newlist{interview}{enumerate}{1}
% make the interview list use \questionansweritem instead of \item
\setlist[interview]{before=\let\item\questionansweritem}

\begin{document}

  \begin{interview}
    \item This is the first question
    \item And this is the answer
    \item This is the second question
    \item Another answer
  \end{interview}

\end{document}
```

If you prefer to use `\question` and `\answer`, which is a good idea because this makes the code more readable, you can do this by adding the lines:

```
\let\answer\questionansweritem
\let\question\questionansweritem
```

The main advantage of using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package is that this makes it easy to change the spacing etc of your list of interview questions -- see the `enumitem` documentation for more details.

You can easily customise your list to allow, for example, the questions to be put in italics:

[image]

This was done using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\realitem\item% save the "real" \item command
\newcommand\questionansweritem{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}
  % \item + turn on italics
  \ifodd\theenumi\realitem[\textbf{Q:}]\bgroup\itshape
  % \turn off italics + \item
  \else\egroup\realitem[\textbf{A:}]\fi
}
\newlist{interview}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[interview]{before=\let\item\questionansweritem}
\let\answer\questionansweritem
\let\question\questionansweritem

\begin{document}

  \begin{interview}
    \question This is the first question
    \answer And this is the answer
    \question This is the second question
    \answer Another answer
  \end{interview}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. In fact, egreg's answer fulfill my needs at present, but I know myself and sooner or later I will undoubtedly try to further refine my environment, changing indentations, spacing, setting different styles for labels and list contents, etc., and your answer shows me some ways to explore.